# Casting string to int in a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, casting

I'm trying to cast a Matrix of strings to a Matrix of integers,
for example I have `Matrix=[['1','2']['3','4']]`

I'm using split because my Matrix is an input with spaces inside, I just gave this for an example .

and I'm doing this:

```
for arr in Matrix:
     arr=arr.split()
     arr=[map(lambda x:int(x),arr)]
```

for some reason the Matrix remains unchanged, am I missing something?

EDIT THIS IS MY EXECUTABLE CODE:

```
Matrix=[];
while True:
     try:
          arrInput=input('enter');
          Matrix.append(arrInput)
     except (KeyboardInterrupt,EOFError):
          print('done');
          break;
for arr in Matrix:
     arr=arr.split()
```

Comment: Your `Matrix=...` isn't valid Python code. Also, your use of `split` would suggest that your matrix is in fact a list of strings which you split on whitespace, which is incoherent with your first definition. Please edit your question with real, executable Python code.

Comment: The answer of Mogambo would be the solution. Moreover, if `Matrix` really is as given in the text, `split()` does not make sense. Matter of style: use `matrix` not `Matrix`. The latter one usually is used for class names.

Comment: No where in your EDIT do you show where you are attempting to create an `int` object from a `str`.

Comment: PS. you do not need all those semicolons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Matrix syntax is invalid, should rather be:

```
Matrix=[['1','2'],['3','4']]
```

Using [list comprehension](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python):

```
Matrix=[['1','2'],['3','4']]    
print([[int(x) for x in lst] for lst in Matrix])
```

**OR**

(if `map` is how you want it to be in like):

```
print([list(map(int, lst)) for lst in Matrix])
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

[**pyFiddle**](https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/08ad509e-b484-4a9d-a6aa-dd690c5cd54b/?i=true)

**EDIT:**

OP: *The thing is I don't want it to be printed, so when I remove the print I get this error.*

If you do not wish to print it, you may assign it:

```
res = [list(map(int, lst)) for lst in Matrix]
```

Comment: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:

Comment: @AlexK I've also added a online test fiddle.

Comment: The thing is I don't want it to be printed, so when I remove the print I get this error.

Comment: @AlexK, Simply assign it `res = [list(map(int, lst)) for lst in Matrix]` If you don't want to print?

Comment: I get this error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '

Comment: Please look at my edited code, maybe it will make things clear/

Answer (score 1):

Try this using `numpy` (`pip install numpy`):

```
import numpy as np
matrix = [['1', '2'], ['3', '4']]
result = np.array(matrix, dtype=int)
print(result.tolist())
# [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

Comment: 'np is not defined'

Comment: Sorry, you need to import `numpy`: `pip install numpy` and then `import numpy as np`.